# Save JSon data in NSArray

Tags: xcode, arrays, json, nsarray

I'm trying to save some specific JSon data and store them in a simple NSArray.

This is the JSon I have:

```
products = {
    72 =     {
        value_a = "something1";
        value_b = "something2";
        value_c = "something3";
    };

    73 =     {
        value_a = "something1";
        value_b = "something2";
        value_c = "something3";
    };

    74 =     {
        value_a = "something1";
        value_b = "something2";
        value_c = "something3";
    };
    [etc]
}
```

This is how I assign the JSon data in a NSMutableArray.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [json objectForKey:@"products"];
```

What I need is to store, let's say, just value_b of each child in an array. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here is a dictionary containing key/values, where values are also dictionaries. If you need to have an array containing, say value_b, of each of these dictionaries you can have it like this:

```
NSDictionary *products = [json objectForKey:@"products"];
NSMutableArray *b_values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

for (NSDictionary *product in [products allValues])
{
  [b_values addObject:[product valueForKey:@"value_b"]];
}

// Now you have an array with all "value_b" objects
```

Comment: Just a little extra question, @Alladinian. What I don't have always the same name ("value_b" in the previous example) but different things? Let's say the NSMutableArray contains values/keys as following: [link](http://pastebin.com/J7pWfydb)

How do I extract data?

Comment: @aur0n Do you mean that there is a case that you will not know the names of the keys? Because if you know the names, you just do valueForKey:@"foo" (for example) and you're done...

Comment: Yeah, I mean if I don't know the names of the keys.

Comment: @aur0n The link that you've posted is a dictionary not an array. In that case you get an NSArray with all the keys (foo, bar, dunno...) with: `[products allKeys]` and an NSArray with all the values (13,9.8,9.8...) with: `[products allValues]` assuming of course that you have this information stored in an NSDictionary named "products". Also you should really read Apple's [documentation on Collections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i)

Comment: Could you please add the Swift code of this answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what you are using, But I can suggest you to use [SBJsonFramework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework)

This kit has very convenient methods to store json data. Store all Json Data in

> NSMutableDictionary

Then for each object you can extract specific value using key to store them in

> NSMutableArray

Comment: Hi @hp iOS Cover, thanks for your quick reply. I'm using iOS 5 native JSon functions, I don't think I need to use the Framework you suggested, because the NSMutableArray I assign in the last piece of code is (I think) already composed of dictionary keys, but I'm not capable of extracting what I need. Can you help me with that?

Comment: If you are using NSJSONSerialization then, I would suggets that check if you crated the json data & json objects properly.
Bcoz that class also has methods with convenient return types to catch the data accordingly
In your problem it seems that 'products' is json DATA & 72,73,73 are json OBJECTS.