# How to turn JSON data into an array in xcode

Tags: xcode, json

I am fairly new to iOS development and I have been trying to figure out how I can convert the following string into an array and then displaying that array in a UITableView

```
{"Result":"OK","Users":[{"name":"The King","email":"king@gmail.com"},{"name":"The Resteruant","email":"theresturaunt@gmail.com"}]}
```

What I want to get is an array for the "name" and a separate array for "email"

This is what i have so far:

```
    strURL    = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://10.139.10.43/Wolfeboro_Connection/get_business.php"];
    dataURL   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];
    strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", strResult);
```

I have installed a JSON library but I dont know how to use it and how I can get the arrays. Please help with examples.

EDIT: Found a great tutorial that helped me with this problem

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. "What you have here is a dictionary containing key/values, where values are also dictionaries. If you need to have an array containing, say value_b, of each of these dictionaries you can have it like this"

[Save JSON data in a NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9869542/2024168)

Comment: ok in the link you provided me there is one line of code that is confusing me. `NSDictionary *products = [json objectForKey:@"products"];` in this line of code what does the "json" stand for? Xcode is giving me the error of "Use of undeclared identifier json"

Comment: Never mind i found a great tutorial that helped me out http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJZcD3hfs3k

Comment: Awesome. Sorry I didn't see this response sooner.